# VSTS: Save file from Release-Definition (as an artifact)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-aks

I cannot use the Publish Build Artifacts Task in a release-definition, I'm getting the following error:

- ErrorHostTypeNotSupported: This task must run in a build to publish artifacts to Visual Studio Team Services/TFS.

So my question is:

- How can I save a file from a release-definition?

Why I want to achieve this:

- I'm using a Deploy to Kubernetes Task in my release definition (which deploys a microservice with a yaml file to azure aks), this yaml file is tokenized during the release (I'm replacing the build-id). So at the end, I want to be able to download this file for each release and to use it for a manual deployment (if necessary).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Publish it as an artifact in your build?

Comment: As Eddie said that the better way is using uploadfile logging command.

Answer (score 3):

There is no container for artifacts in Release Management, so you cannot use that task in Release.

As a workaround, you can use `##vso[task.uploadfile]local file path` command in [VSTS Task Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to upload the file.

> Upload user interested file as additional log information to the
>   current timeline record. The file shall be available for download
>   along with task logs.

To do this, add a powershell task in your release definition like below:
[image]
When you want to use the file, download the release logs as zip, the file will be included in it.